# react native send props to components when declare object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to send into my componentsObject in FooScreen any props and to use it into the components, but it not let me use it.

```
   const FooScreen = ({props}) => <Center><Text>{props}</Text></Center>;
const BarScreen = () => <Center><Text>Bar</Text></Center>;

const components = {
  Foo: FooScreen({name:'test1'}),
  Bar: BarScreen({name:'test2'}),
};

const Center = ({ children }) => (
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }}>{children}</View>
);


const pages = [
    { screenName: 'Foo', componentName: 'Foo' },
    { screenName: 'Bar', componentName: 'Bar' },
  ];
```

i send it as props in Screen and in other screen i try to use it as

```
class TabBarView extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tabs: ''
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props)
}
componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props)
    const {pages,components} = this.props
    setTimeout(() => {
        const screens = {};
        pages.forEach(page => {
          screens[page.screenName] = { screen: components[page.componentName] };
        });
        this.setState({ tabs: TabNavigator(screens) });
      }, 2000);
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.tabs) {
        return <this.state.tabs />;
      }
      return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
    }
}
```

it fail and not let me do that.
later, I want to use in FooScreen as real screen in react and set it into stackNavigator

I get the error

> The component for route 'Foo' must be a react component

Comment: You're missing a comma `,` after `Foo: FooScreen({name:'test1'})`

Comment: Posting your error message would be super useful, as @BrunoEly mentioned you're missing a comma.

Comment: I edited my post, you can see the full example and the error I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the component returns function instead of React element. It's easy to assign a key for each element.
The `setState` should not be used in componentWillMount, especially when there is a timer to cause side-effect.
For efficiency reason, I tested the code below on web. If you replace `div` with `View` and `p` with `Text`, this should work in React Native. Don't forget `import { Text, View } from 'react-native'`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const FooScreen = props => (
  <Center>
    <Text>{`[Foo] ${props.name}`}</Text>
  </Center>
);
const BarScreen = props => (
  <Center>
    <Text>{`[Bar] ${props.name}`}</Text>
  </Center>
);

const components = {
  Foo: (key) => <FooScreen name="test1" key={key} />,
  Bar: (key) => <BarScreen name="test2" key={key} />,
};

const Center = props => (
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
    {props.children}
  </View>
);

const pages = [ 'Foo', 'Bar' ];

export default class TabBardiv extends Component {
  state = {
    tabs: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(pages);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ tabs: pages });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.tabs) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    const screens = pages.map((page, index) => {
      const element = components[page];
      console.log(element);
      return element(index);
    });
    return screens;
  }
}
```

Comment: where you use the const screens?  you just write it without use or call them.

Comment: All the `const` screens are stateless components. Refer this example to export it https://gist.github.com/coryhouse/06835db957f655546c67#file-helloworld-js. I sest up it this way, so the components object accepts key value and return a React element.

Comment: Please replace the `<p>` tage with `<Text>` and '<div>' with '<View>' in react-native. I tested on web page, because the idea is the same, and this is faster to test if it works or not.